# R plotting a graph with different groups of data

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b<-c(2,2,2,2,4,5,6,8,4,1)
c<-c("red","red","red","blue","blue","blue","orange","orange","orange","orange")

data<-data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c)
```

I now want to plot the data on a graph with each group having a different colour:

```
plot(a[c=="red"],b[c=="red"],col="red",xlim=c(min(a),max(a)),ylim=c(min(b),max(b)))
points(a[c=="blue"],b[c=="blue"],col="blue")
points(a[c=="orange"],b[c=="orange"],col="orange")
```

This works fine - however, say if I have 30 groups, the task of writing the code becomes tedious.  I am wondering if there is a better way of writing the code such that R will automatically plot the graph and give different colours to different groups?

Also, I wonder if there is a quick way to display a legend in the graph.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
with(data,plot(a,b,col=c))
```

The `col` argument in `plot()` stands for color. This can contain a vector of the colors you want.

Additionally, you don't have to make a column just to define the color if the color-group relationship is not that important. For example, you could make column `c` a more meaningful column like this:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b<-c(2,2,2,2,4,5,6,8,4,1)
c<-c(rep('Group1',3),rep('Group2',3),rep('Group3',4))

data<-data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c)
```

Then to plot, use:

```
with(data,plot(a,b,col=c))
```

To add a legend:

```
legend('topleft',legend = levels(data[,'c']),col=1:nlevels(data[,'c']),pch=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=a, y=b, colour=c)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: I had a hard time running this.  This `ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=a, y=b, colour = c)) + geom_point()` worked instead.